# Custom Form Flask Security Register

Tags: python, flask-security

i am following the official documentation for flask-security customizing views
https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/customizing.html

i have extented the Form

```
class ExtendedRegisterForm(RegisterForm):
    first_name = StringField('First Name', [Required()])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name', [Required()])
security = Security(app, user_datastore, register_form=ExtendedRegisterForm)
```

here is my user class

```
class User(db.Document, UserMixin):
    email = db.StringField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = db.StringField(max_length=255)
    first_name = db.StringField(max_length=255)
    last_name = db.StringField(max_length=255)
    active = db.BooleanField(default=True)
    confirmed_at = db.DateTimeField()
    last_login_at = db.DateTimeField()
    current_login_at = db.DateTimeField()
    last_login_ip = db.StringField(max_length=40)
    current_login_ip = db.StringField(max_length=40)
    login_count = db.IntField()

    roles = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField(Role), default=[])
```

but rendering the view gives me a jinja template error

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
```

UndefinedError: 'flask_security.forms.ConfirmRegisterForm object' has no attribute 'first_name'

what am i missing?

Comment: did you ever solve this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Did either of you solve this problem? I am having the same one.

Comment: This is likely due to a form type mismatch around `SECURITY_CONFIRMABLE`. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56155594/1749551) for more.

Answer (score 3):

I had a student ask me this same question and came across this post. It's been years since it was asked, but I thought I'd answer the question in case someone else comes along looking for assistance with this same problem.

**FYI:** [Flask-Security](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security) is no longer being maintained. The current package is [Flask-Security-Too](https://github.com/Flask-Middleware/flask-security).
PyPi URL: https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Security-Too/

When you have the variable `SECURITY_CONFIRMABLE` set to `True` you need to make the following changes.

One thing to note before I go into what the changes are is that the register_form where "confirm password" is the norm the confirm_register_form, "password confirm" is not supported as per the official documentation, as it's arguably not needed and makes it easier on the end user. The end user receives an email to confirm their account, and in turn, there is no need to confirm the password, "arguably" :).

Here are the changes you need to make.

**Change:**

```
class ExtendedRegisterForm(RegisterForm):
    first_name = StringField('First Name', [Required()])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name', [Required()])
security = Security(app, user_datastore, register_form=ExtendedRegisterForm
```

**To:**

```
from flask_security.forms import ConfirmRegisterForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class ExtendedConfirmRegisterForm(ConfirmRegisterForm):
    """Additional Fields For User Registration Form"""
    first_name = StringField('First Name', validators=[DataRequired(message='Your first name is required.'), Length(max=255)])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name'), validators=[DataRequired(message='Your last name is required.'), Length(max=255)])
```

**Change:**

```
security = Security(app, user_datastore, register_form=ExtendedRegisterForm)
```

**To:**

```
security.init_app(app, user_datastore,
                      confirm_register_form=ExtendedConfirmRegisterForm)
```

In the html form you can then use the normal jinja tags

```
{{ register_user_form.first_name(class="") }}
{{ register_user_form.first_name.label(class="") }}
{{ register_user_form.last_name(class="") }}
{{ register_user_form.last_name.label(class="") }}
```

That's it :)

**Two threads that go into detail on this are:**
https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/pull/58
https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/issues/54

**Per the documentation**
https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=ConfirmRegisterForm#flask_security.ConfirmRegisterForm

```
class flask_security.ConfirmRegisterForm(*args, **kwargs)

    This form is used for registering when ‘confirmable’ is set. The only difference between this and the other RegisterForm is that this one doesn’t require re-typing in the password…

    We want to support OWASP best-practice around mitigating user enumeration. To that end we run through the entire validation regardless - this allows us to still return important bad-password messages. In the case of an existing email or username - we set form.existing_xx so that the view can decide how to match responses (e.g. json responses always return 200).
```

[7](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Security/): I had a student ask me this same question and came across this post. It's been years since it was asked, but I thought I'd answer the question in case someone else comes along looking for assistance with this same problem.

**FYI:** [Flask-Security](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Security/) is no longer being maintained. The current package is Flask-Security-Too.

When you have the variable `SECURITY_CONFIRMABLE` set to `True` you need to make the following changes.

One thing to note before I go into what the changes are is that the register_form where "confirm password" is the norm the confirm_register_form, "password confirm" is not supported as per the official documentation, as it's arguably not needed and makes it easier on the end user. The end user receives an email to confirm their account, and in turn, there is no need to confirm the password, "arguably" :).

Here are the changes you need to make.

**Change:**

```
class ExtendedRegisterForm(RegisterForm):
    first_name = StringField('First Name', [Required()])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name', [Required()])
security = Security(app, user_datastore, register_form=ExtendedRegisterForm
```

**To:**

```
from flask_security.forms import ConfirmRegisterForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class ExtendedConfirmRegisterForm(ConfirmRegisterForm):
    """Additional Fields For User Registration Form"""
    first_name = StringField('First Name', validators=[DataRequired(message='Your first name is required.'), Length(max=255)])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name'), validators=[DataRequired(message='Your last name is required.'), Length(max=255)])
```

**Change:**

```
security = Security(app, user_datastore, register_form=ExtendedRegisterForm)
```

**To:**

```
security.init_app(app, user_datastore,
                      confirm_register_form=ExtendedConfirmRegisterForm)
```

In the html form you can then use the normal jinja tags

```
{{ register_user_form.first_name(class="") }}
{{ register_user_form.first_name.label(class="") }}
{{ register_user_form.last_name(class="") }}
{{ register_user_form.last_name.label(class="") }}
```

That's it :)

**Two threads that go into detail on this are:**
https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/pull/58
https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/issues/54

**Per the documentation**
https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=ConfirmRegisterForm#flask_security.ConfirmRegisterForm

```
class flask_security.ConfirmRegisterForm(*args, **kwargs)

    This form is used for registering when ‘confirmable’ is set. The only difference between this and the other RegisterForm is that this one doesn’t require re-typing in the password…

    We want to support OWASP best-practice around mitigating user enumeration. To that end we run through the entire validation regardless - this allows us to still return important bad-password messages. In the case of an existing email or username - we set form.existing_xx so that the view can decide how to match responses (e.g. json responses always return 200).
```

Comment: upvote because the doc this information is not put forward in the customizing doc page